# shell scripts that respond to console output

Tags: shell, shell-script, subversion

*Disclaimer:: I am not an active shell scripter*

How does one create a script that responds to console output? For instance, I'm trying to setup a cron that periodically svnsync 's changes to my repository to a backup server every midnight. The problem is, in order to sync, it prompts for authorization credentials.

svnsync sync  accepts no options to specify a login thus a simple cron command is out. I believe I can launch a script but I'm trying to figure out how to make it respond to console output.

For instance:

```
ken@server:~$ svnsync sync https://svn3.backup.net/svn/mirror
Authentication realm: <https://svn3.backup.net/svn/mirror:443> backup.net Subversion Backup
Password for 'ken':
***<send return key>***
Username:***<specify backup.net username>***
Password for '<the name>':***<specify password for username>***
<It proceeds to check out>
```

where `***< message >***` is the action I want the script to respond to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in doubt when you said "svnsync sync accepts no options to specify a login" so I checked the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.html) and guess what, it **does**:

```
--source-password
--source-username
--sync-password
--sync-username
```

Those options should be enough for you to go back to a simple cron script.

Back into the case where you **really** can't specify such options, it is still easy to write a wrapper script that sends data to the program's stdin. For example the following *may* work (where `program` is the program you wan to run, and `text` is a file where you store text to be sent to the program):

```
program < text
```

However, for authentication, programs are often written to ready from `tty` and not from `stdin` (for security reasons). I'm not familiar with it, but you can still create a fake terminal in that case. This is where [`expect`](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-9.html) comes into use.

Comment: I thought those options were specific to an option other than sync, I suppose I read wrong. Thank you clarifying my misconception and answering my misinformed question simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

`expect` might help.

There's a [O'Reilly tutorial](http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html).

Comment: Ah yes that solves my question precisely!

Answer (score 1):

Except this means putting passwords in clear in some script.
Not a very good idea.

Does svnsync not have options for ssh keys?

Comment: SSH keys won't do a lot of good if it's http authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Two similar solutions:

- `expect` (as given by other answers), which requires TCL.
- `pexpect`, written in pure Python.